# change the xlmns value without modifying the prefix using xslt (with built in templates)

Tags: xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces

Source XML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PREMIS:premis xmlns:PREMIS="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2" version="2.2">
    <PREMIS:object xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="PREMIS:file">
        <PREMIS:objectIdentifier>
            <PREMIS:objectIdentifierType>Docuteam</PREMIS:objectIdentifierType>
            <PREMIS:objectIdentifierValue>_20161027171024801</PREMIS:objectIdentifierValue>
        </PREMIS:objectIdentifier>
        <PREMIS:objectCharacteristics>
            <PREMIS:compositionLevel>0</PREMIS:compositionLevel>
            <PREMIS:fixity>
                <PREMIS:messageDigestAlgorithm>SHA-512</PREMIS:messageDigestAlgorithm>
                <PREMIS:messageDigest>2b9be7ebeae4135b0002cfcd7ee4ee2f5d93e80bfabebf6d5d409e504ad1cbd920487f56726362c2a2979b68d96b1c26f37a73e68c30dd9f8cf11502c634ff5a</PREMIS:messageDigest>
            </PREMIS:fixity>
            <PREMIS:size>32783388</PREMIS:size>
            <PREMIS:format>
                <PREMIS:formatDesignation>
                    <PREMIS:formatName>Tagged Image File Format</PREMIS:formatName>
                </PREMIS:formatDesignation>
                <PREMIS:formatRegistry>
                    <PREMIS:formatRegistryName>PRONOM</PREMIS:formatRegistryName>
                    <PREMIS:formatRegistryKey>fmt/353</PREMIS:formatRegistryKey>
                </PREMIS:formatRegistry>
            </PREMIS:format>
        </PREMIS:objectCharacteristics>
        <PREMIS:originalName xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple"
            >12448399.tif</PREMIS:originalName>
    </PREMIS:object>
    <PREMIS:event>
        <PREMIS:eventIdentifier>
            <PREMIS:eventIdentifierType>Docuteam</PREMIS:eventIdentifierType>
            <PREMIS:eventIdentifierValue>_20161027171025082</PREMIS:eventIdentifierValue>
        </PREMIS:eventIdentifier>
        <PREMIS:eventType>Creation</PREMIS:eventType>
        <PREMIS:eventDateTime>2016-10-27T17:10:25</PREMIS:eventDateTime>
        <PREMIS:eventDetail>Performed by: &apos;INGEST-01$&apos;</PREMIS:eventDetail>
        <PREMIS:eventOutcomeInformation>
            <PREMIS:eventOutcome>Success</PREMIS:eventOutcome>
        </PREMIS:eventOutcomeInformation>
        <PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifier xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            xlink:type="simple">
            <PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifierType>Docuteam</PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifierType>
            <PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifierValue>_20161027171024801</PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifierValue>
        </PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifier>
    </PREMIS:event>
    <PREMIS:event>
        <PREMIS:eventIdentifier>
            <PREMIS:eventIdentifierType>Docuteam</PREMIS:eventIdentifierType>
            <PREMIS:eventIdentifierValue>_20161027171031973</PREMIS:eventIdentifierValue>
        </PREMIS:eventIdentifier>
        <PREMIS:eventType>Fixity Check</PREMIS:eventType>
        <PREMIS:eventDateTime>2016-10-27T17:10:31</PREMIS:eventDateTime>
        <PREMIS:eventDetail>Based on sa_ub-erara-01_dss-01. Performed by:
            &apos;INGEST-01$&apos;</PREMIS:eventDetail>
        <PREMIS:eventOutcomeInformation>
            <PREMIS:eventOutcome>Success</PREMIS:eventOutcome>
        </PREMIS:eventOutcomeInformation>
        <PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifier xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            xlink:type="simple">
            <PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifierType>Docuteam</PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifierType>
            <PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifierValue>_20161027171024801</PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifierValue>
        </PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifier>
    </PREMIS:event>
</PREMIS:premis>
```

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:PREMIS="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple"
  >
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>     
    </rdf:RDF>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PREMIS:premis">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="PREMIS:object"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="PREMIS:event"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
  </xsl:template>   

  <xsl:template match="PREMIS:object">  

    <!-- Verknüpfung zwischen Fedora- und PREMIS-Objekt -->
    <!-- Der Identifikator des Fedoraobjektes "info:fedora/CH-001898-1:X" ist nicht im PREMIS-XML gespeichert, sondern muss irgendwie extern eingefügt werden -->

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="info:fedora/CH-001898-1:7">
      <PREMIS:hasObject><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:objectIdentifier/PREMIS:objectIdentifierValue"/></PREMIS:hasObject>
    </rdf:Description>

    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>

    <!-- PREMIS:object -->
    <!-- Ebene1 -->

    <rdf:Description>
      <xsl:attribute name="rdf:about">
        <xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:objectIdentifier/PREMIS:objectIdentifierValue"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <PREMIS:hasIdentifier><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:objectIdentifier/PREMIS:objectIdentifierValue"/><xsl:text>objectIdentifier</xsl:text></PREMIS:hasIdentifier>
      <PREMIS:hasOriginalName><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:originalName"/></PREMIS:hasOriginalName>
    </rdf:Description>

    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>

    <!-- Ebene2 -->

    <rdf:Description>
      <xsl:attribute name="rdf:about">
        <xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:objectIdentifier/PREMIS:objectIdentifierValue"/><xsl:text>objectIdentifier</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
      <PREMIS:hasIdentifierType><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:objectIdentifier/PREMIS:objectIdentifierType"/></PREMIS:hasIdentifierType>
      <PREMIS:hasIdentifierValue><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:objectIdentifier/PREMIS:objectIdentifierValue"/></PREMIS:hasIdentifierValue>
    </rdf:Description>

    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Events -->
  <!-- Ebene1 -->
  <xsl:template match="PREMIS:event">     
    <rdf:Description>
      <xsl:attribute name="rdf:about">
        <xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:eventIdentifier/PREMIS:eventIdentifierValue"/></xsl:attribute>
      <PREMIS:hasIdentifier><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:eventIdentifier/PREMIS:eventIdentifierValue"/></PREMIS:hasIdentifier>
      <PREMIS:EventDateTime><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:eventDateTime"/></PREMIS:EventDateTime>
      <PREMIS:EventDetail><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:eventDetail"/></PREMIS:EventDetail>
      <PREMIS:hasEventOutcomeInformation><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:eventIdentifier/PREMIS:eventIdentifierValue"/><xsl:text>eventOutcomeInformation</xsl:text></PREMIS:hasEventOutcomeInformation>
      <PREMIS:hasEventLinkingObjectIdentifier><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:eventIdentifier/PREMIS:eventIdentifierValue"/><xsl:text>eventLinkingObjectIdentifier</xsl:text></PREMIS:hasEventLinkingObjectIdentifier>
    </rdf:Description>

    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>

    <!-- Ebene2 --> 

    <rdf:Description>
      <xsl:attribute name="rdf:about">
        <xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:eventIdentifier/PREMIS:eventIdentifierValue"/><xsl:text>eventIdentifier</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
      <PREMIS:hasIdentifierType><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:eventIdentifier/PREMIS:eventIdentifierType"/></PREMIS:hasIdentifierType>
      <PREMIS:hasIdentifierValue><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:eventIdentifier/PREMIS:eventIdentifierValue"/></PREMIS:hasIdentifierValue>
    </rdf:Description>

    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>

    <rdf:Description>
      <xsl:attribute name="rdf:about">
        <xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:eventIdentifier/PREMIS:eventIdentifierValue"/><xsl:text>eventOutcomeInformation</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
      <PREMIS:hasEventOutcome><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:eventOutcomeInformation/PREMIS:eventOutcome"/></PREMIS:hasEventOutcome>
    </rdf:Description>

    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>  

    <rdf:Description>
      <xsl:attribute name="rdf:about">
        <xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:eventIdentifier/PREMIS:eventIdentifierValue"/><xsl:text>eventLinkingObjectIdentifier</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
      <PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifierType><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifier/PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifierType"/></PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifierType>
      <PREMIS:hasLinkingObjectIdentifierValue><xsl:value-of select="PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifier/PREMIS:linkingObjectIdentifierValue"/></PREMIS:hasLinkingObjectIdentifierValue>
    </rdf:Description>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the output xml document I want the value of xmlns:PREMIS to be changed to "http://www.loc.gov/premis/rdf/v1#". So the opening root element should look like this:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:PREMIS="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2" 
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

I've tried several things, also posts I've discovered in here. But I don't get it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Post-Process XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- sample_2.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
exclude-result-prefixes="PREMIS"
xmlns:PREMIS="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple"
>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::* except namespace::PREMIS"/>
        <xsl:namespace name="PREMIS" select="'http://www.loc.gov/premis/rdf/v1#'"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PREMIS:*">
    <xsl:element name="PREMIS:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.loc.gov/premis/rdf/v1#">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::* except namespace::PREMIS"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is that the complete XML? You are missing some end elements.

Comment: @NMGod - It was just code formatting errors. I fixed them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your desired output is a typo, and that you actually want this:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:PREMIS="http://www.loc.gov/premis/rdf/v1#" 
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  ...
</rdf:RDF>
```

In your stylesheet, using the same prefix PREMIS to refer to different namespaces depending on whether you are reading or writing is going to be extremely difficult. Does the prefix in the output really have to be PREMIS, or will some other prefix do? If it does have to be the same (and perhaps anyway) I think my preferred approach would be to post-process the output using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="PREMIS"...>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::* except namespace::PREMIS"/>
    <xsl:namespace name="PREMIS" select="'http://www.loc.gov/premis/rdf/v1#'"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PREMIS:*">
  <xsl:element name="PREMIS:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.loc.gov/premis/rdf/v1#">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::* except namespace::PREMIS"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael! Yes to change the prefix would be the beter approach. Anyway when I post-process it as you propose I get an error in oxygen: 
Fehlerlevel: fatal
Beschreibung: XTDE0430: Cannot create two namespace nodes with the same prefix mapped to different URIs (prefix=PREMIS, URI=http://www.loc.gov/premis/rdf/v1#, URI=info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2)
Anfang: 15:0
URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTDE0430 

The XSLT file I've used is posted above. Did I understood something wrong?

Comment: Try adding copy-namespaces="no" to the xsl;copy element.